# Is there an integrated console in visual studio community like the one in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio, console, visual-studio-2017, console-application, visual-studio-extensions

I searched for an extension but I didn't find any consoles, I only found Terminals, which solves the problem but only when I'm running without debugging which is almost useless.

Answer (score 0):

There are two extension tools in VS IDE called [Open Command Line](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.OpenCommandLine) and [PowerConsole](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JianchunXu.PowerConsole)

You could check them in your VS, it would help us to visit or run project file or command lines.